# Google Maps based benchmark for browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, google-maps

Anyone knows if there is any benchmark done to browsers in a "google maps" test suite?

Google Maps with lots of markers and data can really get slow so maybe this was an interesting "real world" benchmark that stresses javascript / DOM management in browsers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider the benchmark data for the tests carried out in this article:

- [**In Usability We Trust - Handling Large Amounts of Markers in Google Maps**](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/01/handling-large-amounts-of-markers-in-google-maps/)

---

[In Usability We Trust - Handling Large Amounts of Markers in Google Maps http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/2214/googlemaps.png](http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/2214/googlemaps.png)

Chrome and Safari end up on top in 5 out of 6 tests, while IE8 ranks last for all tests except one. Make sure to check the above mentioned article for the details of each test.